# How to add class module(which is not going to be displayed) to director class?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I have an object class named bird.lua and i just want to use that class while initiliazing and adding attiributes to the birds. Can i use it with director class? Actually, my question is that do i need to arrange all my lua files according to director class? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes totally can do that; I personally used director class in a object oriented hierarchy in one my my games.

It is pretty effective to use  [OWL (Objects with Lua)](http://developer.coronalabs.com/code/owl-objects-lua)

I created my inheritance with OWL and used these objects with director class easily;

I can support you a sample code if you need further assistance.